# Can't seem to get perl files to work over Web Server host

Tags: html, perl, webserver, cgi, abyss

Trying to run the code on my local host which is using Abyss to host returns a generic 'You have chosen to open:' windows popup.

I'm a real beginner to HTML 5 so sorry if this is obvious. I'm reading through 'HTML 5 in easy steps' and the book asks me to set up the Abyss Websever service, ActivePerl Community Edition, and use prewritten code.

I've place the code echo.pl into Abyss's htdocs file and I've allow checked localhost/index to verify that Abyss was working for files within it.

I tried reinstalling ActivePerl, looking around the Abyss Server Console in case something wasn't right but nothing I see would help out and I don't want to mess with it too much as I only knew about the program about 2 hours ago.

I'm using windows 10 and Firefox if that helps.

```
<form method="GET" action="http://localhost/echo.pl">
    <p>
        <input type="submit"
        name="My Submit Button Name"
        value="My Submit Button Value">
    </p>
```

The output should automatically make a table with names and values, however the code isn't executable at all. I can post the code to echo.pl but I don't know the language and couldn't condense it down plus I don't think the code is the problem itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not worked with Abyss before, but I have encountered similar symptoms setting up other webservers, such as Apache.  My guess is that your Abyss installation is not configured to treat `.pl` files as *executable*, and so serves them as ordinary content.  (And, since they are not HTML, your browser prompts you for what to do with the file.)

I can suggest googling for, say, "abyss web server enable execution of perl".  The top hit I found with that is:

https://aprelium.com/abyssws/perl.html

At first glance, it looks like the right sort of guidance you need, but I'm guessing some about your specific setup.